# Using a result from SSJS array to populate dropdown HTML list

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, html, ssjs, cloudpage

I'm building a CloudPage which involves the user selecting a Data Extension from a list, and I'd like to populate the dropdown list with a list of data extensions from a specific folder.
I've managed to get the list using a slightly modified version of the WSProxy script detailed [here](https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/contact-builder/dataextensions/retrieve/all.html) (the filter is `CategoryID: 12345` rather than just finding ALL), and the `Write(Stringify(result));` gives me the correct list in this format:

```
["Data Extension One", "Data Extension Two", "Data Extension Three"]
```

Further down the page I have a standard HTML dropdown list, and I'd like to populate the  values list with the contents of `Write(Stringify(result));`. I've followed several guides such as the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895082/javascript-populate-drop-down-list-with-array) and also a more specific SFMC one [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000ISJh1SAH) but I'm getting 500 errors each time (and of course, CloudPages gives you no clue on what has gone wrong).

Can anyone provide me with a simple solution for populating my dropdown options with the contents of `result`?

Clarification: This differs from the related question, in that I need to parse the results of `result` to be usable as `<option value>` options in an HTML dropdown menu.

Comment: Parse the results and use dot notation and index numbers in loop to populate the option list. Use try/catch for better understanding of errors on your CloudPage.